# How do you pass in a PHP variable into an inline javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<div id="test" onclick="someFunction('<?=$some_id[1]?>', this);"><span ></span></div>
```

I'm attempting to pass in a PHP variable into an inline javascript function; however when this function executes onclick, it throws the error (Firebug console):

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

someFunction('
```

Comment: What is the value of `$some_id[1]`?

Comment: Are you creating this code dynamically, meaning after the page loads? If so, this will not work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The only thing that can be passed directly to an event is the Event Object, which is another reason not to use inline JavaScript. Of course, your PHP would have to be written first, otherwise you should look into an AJAX solution.Your code should look more like:

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    var doc = document;
    function E(e){
      return doc.getElementById(e);
    }
    var tst = E('test');
    function anotherFunc(arg1, element){
      // do stuff here
    }
    tst.onclick = function(){
      anotherFunc('<?=$some_id[1];?>', this);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If php short tags are enabled, <?= doesn't need the echo. If the shortags aren't enabled, <?= doesn't work at all. It is best to use the full <?php echo $foo; ?> instead of <?= anyway, since the short version is often disabled on a lot of hosts.

Comment: Thanks for the short tag comments. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is to encode it is json:

```
echo "someFunction(".htmlentities(json_encode($some_id[1]), ENT_QUOTES).", this);";
```

Or if you are in the html context:

```
someFunction(<?php echo htmlentities(json_encode($some_id[1]), ENT_QUOTES); ?>, this);
```

json_encode will make a correct javascript string out of a variety of data types, including strings, numbers,and more. Then htmlentities should always be used when adding anything to html to ensure the quotes don't break that output.

Notice that I did *not* put quotes in the string - json has its own quotes, if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you can use the PHP Short Tags on your hosting service?

For the sake of testing I would try:

```
<div id="test" onclick="someFunction('<?php echo $some_id[1]; ?>', this);"><span></span</div>
```

Does "someFunction" expect a string or an integer for the first variable? As you may not require the single quotes around the variable if it expects an integar.

This is all assuming $some_id[1] contains an integer value.